# how to retrieve facebook posts with latest comment in to wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to show the facebook latest posts with latest comments on my wordpress site. But i don't know how it will work and did not get any idea. I have find lot but that will not work for me. Please suggest me the easiest way like some suggestion with plugin name and some other code tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this plugin `https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-facebook-feed/`

there is shortoce for show facebook posts and you can also check posts comments also.

Comment: its working.... but not even seems good as i want. Because it will refer to the facebook page that i don;t want and the another issue is ..it is not showing the updation syncronously...please suggest me the better one.. thanks for help....